# function is overwriting df instead of expanding it

Tags: r, function

I am new to functions, so I am not sure how can I work around the code to be able to keep expanding my output df *out_df*, instead of overwriting it when it runs for each value on x, which in this case would be each country of the data frame *country*.
My output at the end only has also only the information about Brazil.

Here is the function

```
consume_country_year <- function(x) {
  consume <- filter(data1, Consumer %in% x)%>%
    filter(year %in% c('2014', '2015', '2016'))%>%
    group_by(year)%>%
    summarise(Value=sum(Value))
    
  return(consume)
}

country <- c("China", "Germany", "USA", "Brazil")

for (x in country) {
  out_df <- consume_country_year(x)
  
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In R you usually build a list by calling something like `lapply(country, consume_country_year)`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to avoid looping entirely if you instead add `Consumer` as another grouping variable:

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>%
  filter(
    Consumer %in% c("China", "Germany", "USA", "Brazil"),
    year %in% c('2014', '2015', '2016')
  ) %>%
  group_by(Consumer, year) %>%
  summarise(Value=sum(Value), .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to make it as a function because I want to learn how to do them but completely suck at them. But this works and is definitely the easiest way to achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
out.list <- list()
for (i in seq_along(country) {
   out.list[[i]] <- consume_country_year(country[i])
}
out.df <- dplyr::bind_rows(out.list)
```

Comment: This works! The only problem is that I am loosing the Country column, so I am not able to tell to which country each value belongs .

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
for (x in country) {
  out_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(get0("out_df"),consume_country_year(x))
  
}
```

Comment: This works! The only problem is that I am loosing the Country column, so I am not able to tell to which country each value belongs .